# Как сделать чтобы искало полностью строку в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

Имеется библиотека re, с помощью нее хочу найти из огромного текста ссылку, но нахожу только часть от нее, хотя там есть ещё 3 таких же части.
Код внизу
Text : https://pastebin.com/XFk47WMm

```
import re
mail1 = IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.ru')
mail1.login("abcde.....@list.ru", "xxxxxx")

mail1.list()
mail1.select("inbox")

result1, data1 = mail1.search(None, "ALL")

ids1 = data1[0]
id_list1 = ids1.split()
latest_email_id1 = id_list1[-1]

result1, data1 = mail1.fetch(latest_email_id1, "RFC822")
raw_email1 = data1[0][1]
raw_email_string1 = raw_email1.decode('utf-8')
print(raw_email_string1)
ktlink=raw_email_string1.split('https://help.steampowered.com/wizard/HelpUnauthorizedLogin')[0].split('.')
print(ktlink)
```

Comment: Код не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/UQflym/1